# RabbitMQ Shovel Stuck in 'Terminated' Status

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

We have an issue where once in a while, a dynamic shovel (created via the HTTP API: `/api/parameters/shovel/`) with `src-delete-after` set to `queue-length` finishes and then instead of being deleted, gets stuck in a **terminated** status.

Subsequent attempts to delete the shovel by any of the following methods are unsuccessful:

1. Posting a `DELETE` to `/api/parameters/shovel/`
2. `rabbitmqctl delete_shovel`
3. `rabbitmqctl clear_parameter -p <vhost> shovel <shovel_name>`

The shovel doesn't even appear in the 'Shovel Management' section of the RabbitMQ admin UI.

The only way we could get rid of that stuck shovel is by restarting RabbitMQ.

Is anyone else having this issue? If so, how do we clear the shovel without having to restart the cluster? Also, is it possible to prevent this from happening via configuration?

Thanks!

PS:

1. RabbitMQ version: 3.4.4
2. Running a 2 node cluster (will be making it a 3 node cluster shortly due to obvious issue we could face in the case of a network partition).

[image: RabbitMQ Shovel Stuck in 'Terminated' Status]

Comment: I currently have the exact same problem and I'm using RMQ 3.7.13 and Erlang 21.3.1. All 3 commands fail for me. The API returns 405 method not allowed. The CLI returns "Parameter does not exist". Both the UI and /api/shovels shows 2 zombie shovels, but no way for me to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very, very old version of RabbitMQ. Please upgrade to the latest version (`3.7.6`) and be sure to use Erlang `20.3.X` (not `21`).

Answer (score 2):

We're using RMQ 3.7.13, Erlang 21.3.1.

*One* possible way the problem happens:

- 3 node HA cluster
- restart one of the nodes (/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server restart)
- old shovels AND old queues get resurrected somehow

The shovels can't be deleted using any of the ways mentioned in the question.
The only way I was able to get the shovels removed was to disable the shovel plugin on all 3 nodes in the cluster, then re-enable each plugin on each node like so:

```
rabbitmq-plugins disable rabbit_shovel
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbit_shovel
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbit_shovel_management
```

As far as the old queues getting resurrected (happens randomly not touching anything... I call them "zombie" queues), this problem happens about once a month, so I created PostMan scripts to delete the resurrected queues. This has been a problem for years. We upgraded RMQ in hopes that fixes the issue... but it doesn't. Perhaps Quorum queues are a more robust solution? If I had more time to investigate/experiment, I would, but I'm buried up to my eyeballs with higher priorities.